# How to change a file after pull request is raised

Tags: git, github

Let me rephrase the question - so I already have pushed the code to my branch A and its under review for file someTableEntries.csv. I would eventually like to merge it into the master branch.
At the same time "Another Coder" merges changes to someTableEntries.csv into the master branch.

Is there any way that I can resolve conflicts between the someTableEntries.csv I wanted to merge and the one "Another Coder" has already merged. Eventually I would like the file someTableEntries.csv within the master branch containing changes from both my work and that of "Another Coder". Is there something similar to perforce merge tool over here.

Comment: You can add a new commit and just push if PR is not merged. If you are changing the commit which is already pushed by amend or rebase you have to do `push -force`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just should commit and push your changes to the same branch. Pull request will be automatically updated since pull request is a relation of two branches, not a relation between a separate commit and the branch to merge to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can directly add new commit and push to the branch from that you have sent the pull request, but this works only if the pull request is not merged yet.

If pull request got merged before your newest commit then you have to send new pull request for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just commit and push to your branch and the pull request will be updated if it's not merged yet.

A pull request is a request to merge **all changes** included in a source branch (A) to a target branch (B).

The owner of the target branch B is responsible for accepting the changes that are included in branch A, and allow merging it in branch B. All the changes that have been pushed to the source branch until then will be included in the merge.

At the end of the merging process of a pull request, the owner of the target branch B may decide that the source branch A is no longer needed and delete it afterwards.